# Albanian, usage of definite nominative for proper nouns

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article, albanian

I am learning Albanian using the book "Discovering Albanian". In chapter 2, the book introduces the definitive form of the nominative case and explains how to use it whit proper names.

It is said:

> With feminine names, on the other hand, we use the definite form when we use the names as subjects or as address forms:
> Paola është nga Italia. Paola is from Italy.
> Nga je, Paola? Where are you from, Paola?

However, when I read the wikipedia page for [Evis Kushi](https://sq.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evis_Kushi), nowhere in the article they use the definite form Evisi. For example it is said:

> Evis Kushi lindi më 7 tetor 1975 në Elbasan.

And not "Evisi Kushi ...". The same applies for masculine names (e.g. in the page of [Agim Zajmi](https://sq.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agim_Zajmi), they always use Agim, never Agimi).

So my two questions are

1. Is it correct to say:

- Evisi është nga Shqipëria. (definite)
- Nga je, Evisi? (indefinite)

2. Why in Wikipedia they always use the indefinite (Elvis, Agim) form?
3. If Paola is the definite form, what is the indefinite form?